# Tests being run from imported class

Tags: python, pytest

I have a base class with some tests similar to this:

```py
class TestA:
    def test_something(self):
        data = self._generate_some_data()
        assert something_about_data

    def _generate_some_data(self)
        return some_data
```

And another class that reuses the testing logic within `TestA` but providing different data:

```py
# This is the line that is giving me a problem
from somemodule import TestA

class TestB(TestA):
     def _generate_some_data(self)
        return some_other_data
```

Note that I am doing this and not simply creating another test in `TestA` because they each test a different class `A` and `B` (though the classes have the same interface)

The problem I am running into is, when importing `TestA` in the `TestB` module, the name is declared in the module's namespace and therefore its found by `pytest` when searching for tests.

This results in `TestA` tests being run twice: one when its module is found and scanned, and another time when `TestB` module is scanned.

I have thought of two solutions:

1. A simple work around: renaming `TestA` upon import so that it is not found by `pytest` scanning:

```py
from somemodule import TestA as BaseTestA

class TestB(BaseTestA):
    ...
```

2. I could extract the common logic to an abstract class whose name will not match `pytest` search, and that could be safely imported and inherited from by both test classes.

The first option, I do not like it, as it seems hacky. And regarding the second option, I would not really want to extract the logic to another class.

Is there another way to solve this problem that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
import somemodule

class TestB(somemodule.TestA):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes the answer is so obvious its even hard to see 